# how to display the street view area in the google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented the street view of the google map using the google javascript api v3 and i want to show the blue shadow area in google map according to their corresponding street view display.

Can anyone help me out to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "StreetviewOverlay" is not available in v3.  If you would like it, you can star (vote for) this [Enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3178)

(doesn't seem to be a lot of interest in it, only 9 stars so far)